# Ошибки при создании процедуры Oracle

Tags: oracle

Суть задачи такова: В одной схеме есть 2 таблицы, одна из них как: "одна ко многим", и так получается что иногда данные с родителя могут удалятся, а в дочерней остаются и валяются как мусор, тригер конечно был написан но хотелось бы в целях обучения научится создавать процедуру и запускать ее по заданию например 1 раз в сутки на проверку мусора. Написав следующий pl/sql:

```
Create or replace procedure test_proc
    is test number; -- без этого поля не удается   создать так и не нашел для каких целей это. И зачем после select писать into test ....
Begin
    Select t1.tab_Id into test from test_tab1 t1
    where t1.tab_Id not in (select t2.t_Id from test_tab2 t 2);
End;
```

Сейчас сделано просто на выборку полей без удаления, не акцентируйте свое внимание на этом, знаю что должно быть `delete from... where ...` Но в тесте и так не работает. Как все-таки сделать правильно хранимую процедуру или нужна функция? Немного запутался. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать задачу?

Возникают следующие ошибки:

> 1. ORA-01403 данные не найдены.
> 2. Ora-06512 на "test_proc", line 5.
> 3. Ora-06512 на line 2

Comment: Опишите что именно не работает: если возникают ошибки, то укажите полностью тексты сообщений об ошибках; если процедура работает не так как ожидалось, то опишите что именно ожидалось и что именно пошло не так.

Comment: @default locale 1: ORA-01403 данные не найдены. 2: Ora-06512 на "test_proc", line 5. 3: Ora-06512 на line 2

Comment: И обьясните зачем писать into посе select ? Если я буду писать delete from ... Надо будет так же инто писать? А без into можно обойтись ? Спасибо.

Comment: Это прям полный текст процедуры с многоточиями? Если нет опубликуйте полный, пожалуйста (под вопросом есть кнопка «править»)

Comment: @defaul locale да это весь код ... Там где написан комментарий, в главной процедуре его нет, и там где test.... Тоже к комментарию относится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ORA-01403 данные не найдены.

Эта ошибка говорит о том, что запрос вернул пустой результат, т.е. нет строк удовлетворяющих условию. Ошибка возникает т.к. Вы попытались присвоить результат запроса переменной, об этом ниже.

> так и не нашел для каких целей это. И зачем после select писать into 
>   test ....

[`SELECT INTO`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm) используется чтобы получить одиночное значение запросом и присвоить это значение переменной (`test`). Это нужно если переменную планируется использовать в дальнейшем, например:

```
v_selected_id number;
begin
  select --что-нибудь
  into v_selected_id --в переменную v_selected_id
  from ---дальше обычный запрос;

  -- где-то дальше используем переменную
  delete from some_table
  where id = v_selected_id;
```

В процедуре `SELECT` без `INTO` написать не получится, т.к. сама по себе выборка ничего не означает (выбрать записи для чего? что с ними делать?).

Если в процедуре не будет `SELECT INTO`, и переменная `test` использована не будет, то и объявлять ее не понадобится.

> Если я буду писать delete from ... Надо будет так же инто писать?

Нет, не надо, `DELETE` удаляет данные по условию (имеет смысл само по себе), данных не выбирает и, соответственно, `INTO` не поддерживает. Проследите где у Вас будет `COMMIT`.

> Как все-таки сделать правильно хранимую процедуру или нужна функция?

Разница только в том что функция возвращает какой-то результат. Если Вам нужно чтобы оно возвращало результат, пишите функцию, нет — процедуру.

```
--процедура
create procedure p_test is...

--функция
create function f_test return number is
                     --^ единственное отличие 

--разница в использовании
--процедура не возвращает значения
p_test();
-- функция возвращает значение
v_result = f_test();
```

В глобальном смысле, наверное, правильнее будет сохранять целостность данных, [как уже написал @Dmitry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711889/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-oracle#711924).

Comment: default locate спасибо за ответ. А как например вывести число строк в процедуре ? На моем примере? Достаточно добавить count и обьеденить в группу ? Просто у меня так же не получилось ... Что-то не так делаю наверно. Тоесть если писать delete from то и предлог is и as не нужно писать ?

Comment: @Ethernets Весь вопрос в том куда вывести? Сама по себе выборка (`SELECT`) ничего ощутимого не делает, она предназначена чтобы результат использовали в дальнейшем. `is` [нужен](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm), `test number` можно убрать.

Comment: @Ethernets Предлог (на самом деле, это глагол ;) ) `is` - это часть объявления функции/процедуры: `create procedure my_procedure (...) is ...`

Comment: @Dmitry ну да ошибся ))) Спасибо за оивет

Comment: @default locale тоесть если нужно что-то выводить функция подойдет больше. Не до конца понимаю для каких целей нужна процедура если результата не видно )))) можно маленькое объяснение пожалуйста. С точки зрения специалиста. Спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets **Куда** выводить? Что и где Вы хотите увидеть? Разницу между процедурой и функцией я описал в ответе, другой разницы (в том числе с «выводом») — нет.

Comment: @Ethernets процедура, которую Вы написали, ни для каких целей не нужна, она ничего не делает. Если там будет `DELETE` и цель и смысл у нее появится.

Answer (score 2):

Если делать совсем правильно, то вам нужен не триггер, а правильно написанное ограничение целостности, а именно условие `ON DELETE CASCADE`. То есть (простейший пример) первая таблица должна выглядеть так:

```
create table master (
  id number primary key,
  name varchar2(100));
```

Вторая - так:

```
create table detail (
  id number primary key,
  name varchar2(100),
  master_id number references master (id) on delete cascade);
```

Существующее ограничение целостности (`CONSTRAINT`) можно изменить, для этого сначала придется узнать его название (в таблице `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`, например) и написать либо `ALTER TABLE MODIFY CONSTRAINT ...` либо удалить его и создать заново (см. [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001)).
Теперь, с таким констрейнтом, при удалении записи из таблицы `MASTER` связанные с ней данные из таблицы `DETAIL` будут удалены автоматически.

Comment: спасибо вам за помощь, завтра переделаю. Но очень хочется понять как использовать процедуру или функцию не знаю что правильнее для моей задачи. Что бы следить за мусором например 1 раз в сутки используя Jobs